# How to insert result of count query into docs returned from a find query?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a basic find query that gets all user "groups" from the database. For example: `db.groups.find({})`. The result of this looks like this:

```
[{
  name:  'Finance',
  desc:  'The finance team',
  color: '#FF0000'
},
{
  name:  'Sales',
  desc:  'The sales team',
  color: '#008000'
}]
```

Now I also have a users collection, which references one or more of these groups per user. For example:

`db.users.find({})`

```
[{
  firstname:  'Joe',
  lastname: 'Smith'
  groups:  ['Finance'],
},
{
  firstname: 'Jane',
  lastname: 'Smith',
  groups: ['Finance', 'Sales']
}]
```

Essentially, I'm trying to build a query that returns the following results:

```
[{
  name:  'Finance',
  desc:  'The finance team',
  color: '#FF0000',
  user_count: 2
},
{
  name:  'Sales',
  desc:  'The sales team',
  color: '#008000',
  user_count: 1
}]
```

I'm unsure of how to go about this, I'm thinking along the lines of aggregates, or possibly something in the projection?

`db.groups.find({}, {name: 1, desc: 1, color: 1, user_count: ???})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.groups.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "let": { "name": "$name" },
    "pipeline": [{ "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$$name", "$groups"] } } }],
    "as": "users"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "desc": 1,
    "color": 1,
    "user_count": { "$size": "$users" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: That seems to only bring back the fields "name" and "user_count".

Comment: This will bring you the all fields in the `$project` stage.

Comment: Ah, it was a mistake on my end. It works perfectly.